# How do I retrieve 10 days data up to date 'XYZ' from mysql with Perl when some days data are missing, i.e. public holidays

Tags: sql, mysql, perl, datetime

Data is put into a MYSQL DB in the following format:

```
| 2010-03-18 | 1.580 | 1.590 | 1.560 | 1.580 | 164500 |     1.580 |
| 2010-03-19 | 1.570 | 1.570 | 1.560 | 1.570 | 178300 |     1.570 |
| 2010-03-22 | 1.550 | 1.560 | 1.540 | 1.560 | 309000 |     1.560 |
| 2010-03-23 | 1.560 | 1.560 | 1.550 | 1.550 | 284900 |     1.550 |
```

I need to select 10 days of data upto date XYZ, the problem is that some days are missing, i.e. public holidays.

Comment: Die you mean *i.e.* or *e.g.*?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a ten-day range of data, use `WHERE`.  As in,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2010-03-22' AND date <= '2010-03-31' ;
```

If you want ten records, ending a certain day, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= '2010-03-31' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10 ;
```